# Function key allows me to select an entire line - doesn't work on my other windows laptop

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I have 2 dell laptops, both are running Windows 10.

So on Laptop#1 if I go to any text editor and press:

```
function + arrow left/right
```

It allows me to jump to the beginning or end of the current line.

I use this allot in combination of the shift key to allow me to copy/paste an entire sentence.

On laptop#2 for some reason the function key does not behave in this manner, it does nothing when I press the function key + arrow left/right.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> means <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> (I've seen a lot of laptops with this key combination).

Your second laptop may have another combination for <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>, or it may have physical keys.

If you got accustomed to the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> combination, you could use some 'hotkey' tool that will simulate pressing real <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> for your desired combination.